# Unable to register a client to domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have a domain Controller established on the server that uses static IPs. When I attempt to add a System to this domain, it is not successful.

Following is the error details:

```
An error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "abcserver.com".

The error was: "No records found for given DNS query."
(error code 0x0000251D DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.abcserver.com
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try using Windows 2008's in-built DCDiag.exe, to ensure all your DC ducks are in line?

Answer (score 2):

Your Domain DNS zone may not have the proper SRV records registered for the DC.  To re-register the record it's looking for, do one of the following from your DC:

- Run `net stop netlogon`, then `net start netlogon` (Restart netlogon service)
- Run `nltest /dsregdns`

Wait a minute after running these, then try adding the PC again. Although, if your DC SRV records weren't correctly register, you could be having many other problems aside from not being able to add PCs to the domain. Are there any other DCs for this domain?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that this client's DNS settings are correct. AD uses DNS extensively for resource location. Your client tried to issue a DNS query to locate its AD server and it was not able to. The client either needs to be pointed directly at one of your AD DNS servers or (less likely), to another DNS server that has the ability to forward/recurse to your AD DNS servers.

Comment: i have configured client side with the DNS ip =domain controller's ip. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: Well **something** is interfering with the DNS query. Is the DNS service installed and running on the DC? Is there any firewall in play that could block traffic (either network-level or host-level)? Is the subnet mask and gateway correct on this client? You need to double and triple-check this client's settings compared to a DHCP client. **Something** is different - you just need to find that.

Comment: DNS is installed and running on DC.Firewall is off.Subnet mask and gateway are ok. The problem  exists.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct domain name?

Comment: Probably should use nslookup to eliminate the dns issue.  This could just be an error message masking the real issue.